# How to change src code of Vue in node_modules for testing

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am using Vue 2 (doesn't really matter which version exactly).

I want to test some things that happen behind the hood in Vue. So I decided to add `console.log('test123')` in Vue's files in node_modules. It turns out that the console log never fires. I put that in all files of Vue in node_modules, even in all files of dist's folder of Vue.

How can I achieve this ? If I fork the repo, then I'd have to upload new versions each time on my repo and then run npm install. I know that will work but wanted to achieve this without forking.

Any ideas what I am missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are many ways .. but i feel more comfortable using this method :

you can download any npm package in a seperated folder next to your project...

 open the folder of the package then run this in the terminal:

```
npm link
```

then open the project folder and run

```
npm link ../package-path     # link the dir of your dependency
```

**References**
[npm-link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-link) 
[How to test an npm package locally](https://flaviocopes.com/npm-local-package/)